# Doing a WHERE IN on multiple columns in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table 'answers' with an indexed 'problem_id' integer column, a 'times_chosen' integer column, and an 'option' column that's a varchar. Currently the only values for the 'option' column are 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', though those may expand later on. I want to increment by one the 'times_chosen' values of many (50-100) answers, when I know the problem_id and option of each of them.

So I need a query that's something like:

```
UPDATE answers
SET times_chosen = times_chosen + 1
WHERE (problem_id, option) IN ((4509, 'B'), (622, 'C'), (1066, 'D'), (4059, 'A'), (4740, 'A')...)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It should, at least I think it would in MySQL and MSSQL. Have you tried it? You can test it with `SET times_chosen = times_chosen`

Comment: Oh wow, it actually does work, just as I wrote it! It even uses the index! Thanks Dirk - if you just copy your response below as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: heh, I didn't know that was valid syntax.  That's handy =D

Comment: @PreciousBodilyFluids May you please add a line of confirmation in your question that it works like a charm ^^

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should, at least I've done it before in other SQLs.

Have you tried it? You can test it with `SET times_chosen = times_chosen`

Comment: It actually works. Question itself is solution to asked problem. Yet it is not mentioned in the question nor in the answer enough. I've spent some time trying other solutions for delete query until I found out in PostgreSQL docs that this should work too and solves my problem :-)

Answer (score 39):

You can join against a virtual table of sorts:

```
SELECT * FROM answers
JOIN (VALUES (4509, 'B'), (622, 'C'), (1066, 'D'), (4059, 'A'), (4740, 'A')) 
    AS t (p,o)
ON p = problem_id AND o = option
```

You can do something similar with UPDATE.

Comment: Apart from being cooler, is there a reason why this solution is much more up-voted that @Dirk's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6672930/2071807)?

Comment: This works well for postgresql. I need the corresponding query for spring jpa. Can you help ?

Comment: this is more flexible, we can change the operator on a per-column basis.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this if you cast the data to an array first:

```
UPDATE answers
SET times_chosen = times_chosen + 1
WHERE ARRAY[problem_id::VARCHAR,option] IN ('{4509,B}', '{622,C}', ... )
```

However, this will be incredibly inefficient, as it cannot use indexes.  Using a JOIN as suggested by @Frank Farmer is a far better solution:

```
UPDATE answers a
SET times_chosen = times_chosen + 1
FROM (VALUES (4509,'B'), (622,'C') ...) AS x (id,o)
    WHERE x.id=a.problem_id AND x.o=a.option;
```

Answer (score -5):

You're probably looking for the

```
SELECT * FROM foo, bar WHERE foo.bob = "NaN" AND bar.alice = "Kentucky";
```

style syntax.  Essentially, you use tablename.rowname to specify what individual field you're looking for.  In order to line everything up properly, you add WHERE clauses that make sure the primary keys match:

```
...WHERE foo.primarykey = bar.primarykey
```

or similar.  You'd do well to look up inner joins.