# sql - Dynamically select using two lists for the where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-in

I have two lists of values of variable but equal lengths.

```
Example:
vals1: a, b, c
vals2: 1, 2, 3
```

What is the best way to do something equivalent to:

```
select * from table where (col1=vals1[0] and col2=vals2[0]) or (col1=vals1[1] and col2=vals2[1]) or (col1=vals1[2] and col2=vals2[2])
```

Keeping in mind that the length of the lists can be 1 or more and always the same length. I'd love to not loop and build the string if another option exists (preferably in the form of a SQL query). Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use a string-splitter function written for whatever database you are using.  Google knows lots of them.

Comment: What database is this for? SQL dialects differ.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: `where (col1, col2)  in (vals1, vals2)`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672665/doing-a-where-in-on-multiple-columns-in-postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doing a WHERE IN on multiple columns in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672665/doing-a-where-in-on-multiple-columns-in-postgresql)  Look at Frank Famer's response or using where (col1,col2) in (vals1, vals2)

Comment: @xQbert I thought about that, but the problem would be that you'd get every combination (`a/1, a/2, a/3, etc`). But what I'm looking for, I only want: `a/1, b/2, c/3`.

Comment: I disagree `where (col1,col2) in ((vals1[0],vals2[0]),(vals1[1],vals2[1])...)` would operate differently than where `col1 in (vals1)  and col2 in (vals2)`.  In the first case the paird combination must match in the latter, you would get the results mentioned.  Or if you joined on a values table `SELECT * FROM answers
JOIN (VALUES (4509, 'B'), (622, 'C'), (1066, 'D'), (4059, 'A'), (4740, 'A')) 
    AS t (p,o)
ON p = problem_id AND o = option`  then they both have to match.

Comment: http://rextester.com/WAQC21972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unnest` the arrays in parallel

```
select *
from t
where (col1, col2) in (
    select (a,b)
    from (
        select unnest(array['a','b','c']), unnest(array[1,2,3])
    ) s (a,b)
)
```