# Update using range over multiple primary key columns doesn't use index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with two numeric columns as primary key. In a transaction, I select the first (ordered by the primary key columns) N rows (for N=500 or so) for update, process them, then update them.

```sql
SELECT ...
ORDER BY pk1, pk2
LIMIT 500
FOR UPDATE
```

Now, I'm not sure what's the optimal approach to select those rows in the update's `WHERE` clause. I've tried this:

```sql
array[pk1, pk2] >= array[$first_pk1_value, $first_pk2_value]
AND array[pk1, pk2] <= array[$last_pk1_value, $last_pk2_value]
```

(where `pk1` and `pk2` are the primary key columns and `${first,last}_pk{1,2}_value` is the scanned value for the corresponding column for the first and last rows scanned in the select)

Given that arrays are ordered lexicographically, just like `ORDER BY pk1, pk2` does, this finds the right rows.

I've also tried the equivalent:

```sql
(pk1 = $first_pk1_value AND pk2 >= $first_pk2_value)
OR (pk1 > $first_pk1_value AND pk1 < $last_pk1_value)
OR (pk1 = $last_pk1_value AND pk2 <= $last_pk2_value)
```

Both work, but doing a sequential scan. Since the WHERE clause just expresses a range over the primary key, I'd expect Postgres to do an index scan.

Is it that Postgres just doesn't support selecting a range over multicolumn indexes, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: maybe the "in approach" could be better for postgres (sorry, i use oracle. and ms-sql if forced too ;-) ) . like "where (pk1,pk2) in (array[])"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672665/doing-a-where-in-on-multiple-columns-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

In response to Toni's comment, below, I tried to use a tuple as I would in python, and it worked much better than my original suggestion.  Based on the `analyze` output, the implicit `row(id1, id2)` is compatible with the index backing the PK.

```
select version();
                                                                version                                                                 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

explain analyze 
 select * from testidx_array 
  where (id1, id2) between (8, 150) and (9, 2000);

                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on testidx_array  (cost=423.81..1263.91 rows=19855 width=40) (actual time=1.772..4.148 rows=11851 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((ROW(id1, id2) >= ROW(8, 150)) AND (ROW(id1, id2) <= ROW(9, 2000)))
   Heap Blocks: exact=54
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on testidx_array_pkey  (cost=0.00..418.84 rows=19855 width=0) (actual time=1.722..1.722 rows=11851 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((ROW(id1, id2) >= ROW(8, 150)) AND (ROW(id1, id2) <= ROW(9, 2000)))
 Planning time: 0.096 ms
 Execution time: 4.867 ms
(7 rows)
```

**Old Answer, Below, Superseded**

You should be able to force the use of the index by specifying the range for your `pk1` and then including an `and` for the `array[pk1, pk2]` condition.

```
where pk1 between $first_pk1_value and $last_pk1_value
  and array[pk1, pk2] between array[$first_pk1_value, $first_pk2_value] 
                          and array[$last_pk1_value, $last_pk2_value]
```

This worked for me in a test table:

```
\d testidx_array
            Table "public.testidx_array"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id1      | integer |           | not null | 
 id2      | integer |           | not null | 
 somedata | text    |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "testidx_array_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id1, id2)

explain analyze
 select * from testidx_array 
  where array[id1, id2] between array[8,150] and array[9,2000];

                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testidx_array  (cost=0.00..1943.00 rows=500 width=40) (actual time=42.011..50.758 rows=11851 loops=1)
   Filter: ((ARRAY[id1, id2] >= '{8,150}'::integer[]) AND (ARRAY[id1, id2] <= '{9,2000}'::integer[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 88149
 Planning time: 0.151 ms
 Execution time: 51.325 ms
(5 rows)

explain analyze 
 select * from testidx_array 
  where id1 between 8 and 9 
    and array[id1, id2] between array[8,150] and array[9,2000];

                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on testidx_array  (cost=418.85..1258.91 rows=99 width=40) (actual time=2.278..11.109 rows=11851 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((id1 >= 8) AND (id1 <= 9))
   Filter: ((ARRAY[id1, id2] >= '{8,150}'::integer[]) AND (ARRAY[id1, id2] <= '{9,2000}'::integer[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 8149
   Heap Blocks: exact=90
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on testidx_array_pkey  (cost=0.00..418.82 rows=19853 width=0) (actual time=2.138..2.138 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((id1 >= 8) AND (id1 <= 9))
 Planning time: 0.289 ms
 Execution time: 11.693 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! But I'd like to understand why Postgres can't figure this out by itself. Is there a fundamental reason I'm missing or it's just not smart enough (yet)?

Comment: @ToniCárdenas Whoa! Please see my update.  It looks like there is a solution.